# onCreateView value to AsyncLogin

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment

Im a beginner in android, Im wondering as to how to pass data from my oncreateView to my async task. For example I have a user id in my oncreate how can I call this user Id to my asyntask?

here is my code.

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 //   myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.currently_history_rvmainfragment,container, false);
     myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.currently_history_rvmainfragment,container, false);
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    int myInt = bundle.getString("key","")

    //I HAVE A DATA HERE AND I WANT TO PASS IT TO MY ASYNC TASK

    new AsyncLogin().execute();
    return myView;
}

private class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;
    MaincommentShowmore maincommentShowmore= new MaincommentShowmore();

        // I WANT TO PASS IT HERED SO THAT I MAY CALL IT TO MY URL

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();
    }

    @Override //SO THAT I MAY ADD INT VALUES IN THIS URL
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            // Enter URL address where your json file resides
            // Even you can make call to php file which returns json data
            url = new URL("http://192.168.1.6/jmiappphp/showRateCommentShowMore.php");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {

            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass params to the `execute` method as follows,

```
String data1 = "your_data1";
String data2 = "your_data2";

new AsyncLogin().execute(data1, data2);
```

Inside `doInBackground` retrieve it as,

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String data1 = params[0];
    String data2 = params[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks I used this and it worked omg you saved my capstone HAHAHAHA <3 More power

Answer (score 1):

On the onCreateview

```
new AsyncLogin(yourId).execute();
```

And create a constructor in the AsyncTask:

```
int id;

public AsyncLogin(int id) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
}
```